# IE9 Being different yet again

Tags: css, forms, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a html5 form with about 6 input fields, some being required and some optional. Once a field has been filled it, I have made it turn green using the following code:

```
input:valid, textarea:valid { background: #dfd; }
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox however Internet Explorer 9, being what it is, doesn't want to take this CSS code into consideration. Is there any way I could get round this?

Comment: I would suggest you just use Javascript to do this. Would be very simple with JQuery

Comment: is there no way of just using css for this one?

Comment: Well I'm not a css expert. But i don't think there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 9 does not support these Pseudo-classes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx#pseudoclasses

Comment: typical of Microsoft. Thanks for your help and the link, will use this page before I make anymore forms

Comment: If you want text-shadow, IE9 does not support that either.